# Why can't we use APU bleed air for wing anti ice on the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, apu, anti-ice, bleed-air

The question says it all. While reading I came across this that we can under no circumstances use APU bleed air for supplying wing anti ice? Any reason?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On multiple [PPRUNE](http://www.pprune.org/tech-log/532346-a320-apu-bleed-wai.html) threads they **incorrectly** say:

> The APU bleed is much cooler than the engine bleed system, and would be ineffective for WAI.

But [the reason is](https://quizlet.com/55398485/allegiant-a320-ice-rain-protection-flash-cards/):

> The APU bleed temperature is unregulated and thus could damage the wing slats if used for anti-ice.

[image]

Highlight shows regulation of engine bleed temperature.

Comment: Great thanks soo much. A lot of these questions arise in my mind due to they grey areas present in Airbus manuals.