# Can a single engine on an A320 provide wing anti ice?

Tags: airbus-a320, anti-ice

Can a single engine on an A320 provide wing anti ice for both wings in the air ?

Comment: I believe there is an engine bleed cross-over valve that can be opened to supply the other side, but I can't find a diagram of it that shows both sides of the anti-ice system.

Answer (score 7):

It would probably be a single point of failure if one engine wouldn't be enough to deice both wings.

For this reason there is a cross bleed selector so that the remaining engine can feed the wing on the opposing side.

Here is a link to a computer based training video of the A320 explaining that a single engine bleed is enough for both wings but not for both air conditioning packs and wing anti ice at the same time. So to use have wing anti ice with a single engine you need to turn off one pack and enable cross bleed.

Comment: What is a "pack" ?

Comment: @zymhan PACKs are _Pneumatic Air Cycle Kit_s  which are a central part of the A/C system in aircraft cabins and cockpits.

Comment: You cannot use APU bleed air on the 320, it is unregulated and too hot for anti-ice. See: [Why can't we use APU bleed-air for wing anti-ice on the A320?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43075/why-cant-we-use-apu-bleed-air-for-wing-anti-ice-on-the-a320)